# SQL Syntax error - SET

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sql-update

SQL error in a PHP script, I'm very new to SQL. It's probably something silly that's been asked loads before, but I'm probably searching for the wrong thing and therefore can't find an answer - I did look!

**SQL error**
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET approved = '1' WHERE primary = '16'' at line 1

**The problem line:**

```
$query = "UPDATE $table SET approved = '1' WHERE primary = '$id';";
```

**Rest of my code:**

```
<?PHP require ('config.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];


$query = "UPDATE $table SET approved = '1' WHERE primary = '$id';";
$execute = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

if ($execute){
echo "Entry $id successfully approved.";
}


else { echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);};



?>
```

Comment: `$table` is not set. Turn on error reporting and you'll catch things things quicker. Also, your code is wide open to attack.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I thought I'd set that in config but you're right. I also needed the backticks to get it working though. I'm not sure how to turn on error reporting but will look into it. Think I've added htmlspecialchars to the url variable correctly now, is it still unsafe?

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL) as in http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this way to set your `$table` variable first as it causes Syntax Error & add backtick (`) to your primary column name, because it's [RESERV](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) Keyword of MYSQL, But this may be not the main reason here.

```
<?php
  require ('config.php');
 try {
            $id = $_GET['id'];
            $approved=1;
            $table="your_table_name";  // set table name here
            $database="your_database_name";
            $dbUser="your_user_name";
            $dbPass="your_password";
            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=your_host_name;dbname=$database", $dbUser, $dbPass);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE $table SET approved =? WHERE `primary` = ?");
            $stmt->execute(array($approved,$id));
            echo "Entry $id successfully approved.";

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }
?>
```

Comment: This has fixed the issue, (except the missing ; after table name) thank you. Is this safe - $id = htmlspecialchars($_GET['id']);

Comment: @JohnConde, The OP doesn't ask for that so i didn't add that. Please See my Updated answer

Comment: Doesn't matter if they ask for it. They, and other newbies who come accross this answer are gonna cut and paste your answer into their code and be vulnerable to attack. We have a responsibility to give correct and safe answers.

Comment: @JohnConde, Thanks Sir, i didn't thought in that sense. Thanx

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I can't get this new code to work. I replaced the details and get this:

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object on line 13. Line 13 is this for me   " $q->execute(array($approved,$id)); "

Comment: @TomHolmes, Please, check my Updated answer one more time. Try & Let me know it works for you or not?